# How to iterate through a dictionary in swift

Tags: swift, xcode, dictionary, swiftui-foreach, swift-dictionary

When my structure is called/referenced, the country name is passed into it (i.e. "United Kingdom"). I then want to search for all the items that are in that country in the 'items' dict, and display just the description property of each one in a navigation list.

I don't really understand what the problem is, let alone the solution.

Here are the errors:

[image: Here are the errors]

And here are the expanded errors when i click on the first one:

[image: Errors on the ForEach]

Here's the entirety of the code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct CountryView: View {
    var country: String // Country name is passed in when struct called
    
    let items = [
        "United Kingdom": [
            [
                "description":"Diamond-Encrusted Ring",
                "image":"placeholder",
                "category":"jewellery",
                "location":"Tate Modern Museum"
            ],
            [
                "description":"Red Baseball Cap",
                "image":"placeholder",
                "category":"clothing",
                "location":"Old Trafford Stadium"
            ]
        ],
        "United States": [
            [
                "description":"Apple Watch",
                "image":"placeholder",
                "category":"device",
                "location":"Empire State Building"
            ]
        ]
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(items, id: \.self) { item in
                    NavigationLink(destination: ItemView(item: item)) {
                        Text(item.description)
                    }
                }
            }.navigationTitle(country)
        }
    }
}

struct CountryView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        CountryView(country: "United Kingdom")
    }
}
```

I know for a fact that this question is confusing, so feel free to edit it to make it a little clearer. I just can't think of a better way to explain it, since I have no idea what's going on. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should rethink your setup get rid on the dictionaries and use models.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/SwiftUI/ForEach For the list of initializers.

Comment: have you search, for example, `iterate through a dictionary` in SO? Have a look at this:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @loremipsum is a model the equivalent of, say, a python class? cause i know how those work very well

Comment: Yes, a struct would work better better than a class SwiftUI. The difference is reference vs value types.

Answer (score 0):

As per advice from a commenter, I switched to using a model rather than a dict. It worked! Although I'm not sure it was supposed to be a solution, and more just a tip, it solved the problem.